# How to avoid ChunkLoadError when using @loadable/component in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, loadable-component

Solution for this issue is available when using React.lazy:

- https://www.codemzy.com/blog/fix-chunkloaderror-react
- https://raphael-leger.medium.com/react-webpack-chunkloaderror-loading-chunk-x-failed-ac385bd110e0

However we are using `@loadable/component` and it is less clear how we can resolve these ChunkLoadError's when using this module. We just recently started code-splitting in our application, and the headache from these errors has been offsetting any performance gain our web application has gotten.

How can we prevent ChunkLoadError's when using `@loadable/component`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason we were using `@loadable/component` in the first place is for the `.preload()` function. However, until we can resolve this ChunkLoadError issue, we are going to stop using `@loadable/component`.

We've installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazy-with-preload and followed the exact solution in the **medium** post above, except we used `lazyWithPreload` instead of `lazy` within the `lazyWithRetry` function.

We can then load components as such in our **App.js** file:

```
const ShotChartsApp = lazyWithRetry(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "ShotChartsApp" */ './containers/AppPages/ShotChartsApp'));

function App() {
    ...
    // Load the lazy-loaded components
    useEffect(() => {
        ShotChartsApp.preload();
    }, []);
}
```

I am hopeful that this solution handles all 3 of:

- has code splitting so first page load is quick
- preloaded components so that users don't need to wait for components to load as they are being visited
- no `LoadChunkErrors`

fingers crossed that this works...

Comment: I am having trouble with LoadChunkErrors. Did it worked ?